# I want to spatially distribute 1000 mobile devices in a network according to Poisson Point Process in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, distribution, spatial, poisson

I have 1000 mobile devices or Users. 
so Let D= {D_1,D_2,…,D_N}  [the set of devices]. 
I want to spatially distribute them in a Network(Circular Region of Radius 1000m)according to Poisson Point Process where the density rate or Lambda is 100. Each Mobile Device has a Radio Range or Radius(in which it can interact with others) of 200m. Matlab poissrnd function only gives me a random variable. What can I do with it to spatially distribute them?. So i think a set of values giving their location in a Circular area is required. Please inform how to make its algo this keeping in mind that I would later want any device,Di to check in its vincinity(in its radius R=200m) for mobile users and find closest Device,Dj and calculate the displacemnt in meters. Please inform regarding it. I would be obliged.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You show what you've attempted so far, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: @MarcB ok whats the algo. What I have done so far is generated a set of 1000 mobile devices. I have lambda but don't know how to PPP distribute 1000 mobile devices in a Circular region of Radius R=1000m. When it distributes them in a circular Region. I would want their locations. Then since each mobile device has a radio range of 200m. It will look for nearest mobile device. Currently I want to distribute them By PPP and obtain their location values set that gives me their values in metres with respect to centre of circular Region of radius 1000m

Answer (score 0):

Well, a Poisson point process distributes a random number of points in any given area of space and these are distributed independently of each other in the region. If it is a homogeneous Poisson point process with intensity lambda = 100 points/km^2 and you consider a disk with radius 1 km, i.e. area 3.14 km^2 you would expect to see 314 points on average. The number of points is Poisson distributed with this mean (314), and observing 1000 or more points in this distribution is extremely unlikely.

Given the number of points, the individual points are independent and uniformly distributed over the region. So given that you have 1000 points in the disc you simply have to distribute them uniformly in the disc. The most efficient way to do this is to use polar coordinates, but you can also more simply generate one point at a time uniformly in the bounding square and then keep the point if it is inside the disc and reject it otherwise.